# How to pass string as column name in R

Tags: r, dataframe, variables, shiny

```
m ="jan"  
n = "5e"

r = paste0("jan","5e","_results")


"jan5e_results"
```

Now I want to use r's value and select a data frame because I have data frame with names like

```
jan5e_results
feb5e_results
mar5e_results
.
.
.
```

similarly how do I select column name from those data frames?

e.g.

```
jan5e_results will have column name jan_var1
feb5e_results will have column name feb_var1
mar5e_results will have column name mar_var1
.
.
.
```

using variable names how do I select a data frame and column name like

```
m ="jan"  
n = "5e"
r = paste0("jan","5e","_results")
c = paste0(m,"var1")
r$c
```

I am asking this because I am trying to make a small utility in shiny which will take input and based on that I need to select specific data frame and specific column. If there is any better way let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `get`

```
col= paste0(m,"_var1")
get(r)[col]

#  jan_var1
#1        1
#2        2
#3        3
#4        4
#5        5
```

`get(r)` would return the entire dataframe having name as `jan5e_results` and from that we select `col` column to subset.

```
#  jan_var1  b
#1        1  6
#2        2  7
#3        3  8
#4        4  9
#5        5 10
```

**data**

```
jan5e_results <- data.frame(jan_var1 = 1:5, b = 6:10)
```

Comment: It doesn't works with SpatialPolygonsDataFrame
`popup <- paste0("<strong>Name: </strong>", shpFile$SUBZONE_N, " ", 
shpFile_Proj[dfcolName])`

>Error in as.character.default(<S4 object of class "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame">) : 
  no method for coercing this S4 class to a vector

Comment: @newguy not sure what might be wrong. Can you add a reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

You could also save all dataframes in a list and then select them like this

```
col= paste0(m,"_var1")
dflist[[r]][col]

#  jan_var1
#1        1
#2        2
#3        3
#4        4
#5        5
```

The **advantage of this approach** is that you can create the dataframes dynamically, too. What I mean is: Usually, you need to actually type dataframe names to define them, for example with

```
jan5e_results <- data.frame(jan_var1 = 1:5, b = 6:10)
# here you can not define jan5e_results without actually writing jan5e_results
```

But with lists you can simply create dataframes with the names you want to give them inside a list like this

```
dflist[[r]] <- data.frame(matrix(rnorm(length(somevariable)), ncol= ncol(somedataframe)))
```

To be able to reproduce it here the whole code including variables from your question

```
# deciding what elements to choose
r = paste0("jan","5e","_results")
m = "jan" 
col = paste0(m,"_var1")

# vector with dataframe names
dfnames = paste0(c("jan", "feb", "mar"), "5e", "_results")

# creating an empty list
dflist = vector("list", length(dfnames))
# naming the list
names(dflist) = dfnames

# save one of the dataframes to list
dflist[[r]] = data.frame(jan_var1 = 1:5, b = 6:10)
```